# Order products by stock on Magento

Tags: php, magento

How can I order products by stock? This is my query atm:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $cateids = $this->getCategoryId();
    if($cateids) {
        $catIds = explode(',', $cateids);
        $arr_productids = $this->getProductIdsByCategories($catIds);
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addUrlRewrite()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addIdFilter($arr_productids)
            ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            ->setOrder ($fieldorder,$order);
        $products->getSelect()->order('rand()');
    } else {
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addUrlRewrite()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->setOrder ($fieldorder,$order);
        $products->getSelect()->order('rand()');
    }
    $products->setPageSize($this->getProductCount())->setCurPage(1);
    return $products;
```

I tried to put this code:
`->joinLeft(array('bs'=>'cataloginventory/stock_status'), 'bs.product_id = e.entity_id', array('stock_status' => 'bs.stock_status'))->order("stock_status desc")`

But it didn't work out. I want to see the products with higher stock first then the other products.

Comment: which magento version are you using? 1.9.0.2 ???

Comment: if so there's a extension already made for this: [link](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sort-products-automatically-sort-by-stock.html)

Comment: I don't know if that's the case but I'm using a theme, it has it's own "catalog loop" (which i've posted above). I installed the extension but it doesn't work at all. Is it supposed to work alongside the theme?

Comment: the extension works fine with the magento 'default' theme. If you're using your own custom theme, then copy the extentions' files into your own theme's folder...

Comment: ... and don't forget to clear the cache as well to reflect the changes in the frontend

Answer (score 0):

Use the join on product collection below code like-

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->joinField('qty',
         'cataloginventory/stock_item',
         'qty',
         'product_id=entity_id',
         '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
         'left'
     )->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('gt' => 0))->setOrder('qty','DESC');
```